# How to get accent marks on letters in a TextView Android

Tags: java, android, text, textview

I have text that needs to be displayed in Latin. When the textfiles are displayed in the TextView, little diamonds with questions marks in them appear where all the letters should be that have accents on them. Can anyone help? I need to be able to display the text as it is in a PDF. So I got my text files by copying the sections of text out of the PDF and into text files. The code that scans through text files looks like this:

```
public String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader  dataIO = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (is));
    String strLine = null;
    while ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");
    }

    dataIO.close();
    is.close();

    return sBuffer.toString();
}
```

then in the onCreate() I have this:

```
text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    //text.setText("This is a whole lot of text and praying");
    InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(idEng);
    try {

        text.setText(inputStreamToString(iFile));
        text.setFocusable(false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    ELswitch = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    ELswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked==true)
            {
                InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(idLat);
                System.out.println(R.raw.sunday_compline_english);
                try {

                    text.setText(inputStreamToString(iFile));
                    text.setFocusable(false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(idEng);
                try {

                    text.setText(inputStreamToString(iFile));
                    text.setFocusable(false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The toggle button is so that the user can switch back and forth between English and Latin. The problem is that the Latin comes out looking like this (all letters with accents are replaced with an odd question mark symbol):
[image: Problem with accented letters not showing up]

Is this a problem with the text files? Should I be working directly from the PDF? If anybody has any ideas, I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: In your `inputStreamToString(...)` method try creating the reader with explicit encoding... `new InputStreamReader (is, "UTF-8")`

Comment: So I put in the change in the line: BufferedReader  dataIO = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (is, "UTF-8"));

This doesn't fix the issue but it occurred to me that the text files are not saved as UTF-8. Should I change them all? Additionally, I noticed the text files come up with question marks in the viewer for the IDE as well. Should I go back and save them all in UTF-8?

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Changing the files to UTF-8 encoding and specifying the encoder explicitly fixed the problem. Sorry if this sounded like a dumb question. This is my first time working on an Android app. Thanks again.

Comment: I just guessed at the encoding. Android (well Java, actually) uses UTF-8 by default but `InputStreamReader` matches the encoding with the source. I'd recommend always using UTF-8 for any source files if you have the option. Glad I was able to point you in the right direction.